# Three.js HTML menu interaction

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm making an HTML menu that will be placed over the Three.js viewport, but I can't get a reliable interaction with the menu. I can click on my `<input type="range">` sliders and other elements, but I can't drag without the Orbital camera taking all the mouse movement for itself.

Is there a way for me to designate the div as blocking somehow, so it will take the mouse actions before the viewport grabs them?

Comment: Depending on how you control the camera (THREE.OrbitControls or something else?) and the DOM, you may try to disable the controls during the drag or prevent the propagation of the _mousedown_ event which initiates the drag. Can you reproduce your problem in a simple example or provide precision about your implementation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't pass a div to the controls the listeners will be added to the document. Try with this:

```
new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```